# Code Contracts warning not showing

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I have this simple code:

```
public ArrayStack(int capacity)
    {
        Contract.Requires(capacity >= 0);
        Contract.Ensures(_items != null);
        Contract.Ensures(_items.Length == capacity);
        _items = new T[capacity];
        _top = -1;
    }
```

I expected that once I type the followig I will get a compile time warning, but I only get a runtime exception from the contract.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = -1;
        ArrayStack<string> stack = new ArrayStack<string>(i);

    }
```

any ideas?

EDITED: picture of my code contract settings
[image]

Comment: Silly question, but are you actually running the validator? (What are your settings, etc?)

Comment: @JonSkeet -  Sure I practically marked everything there :) I am getting the runtime validation. is there anything in particular I should pay attention to in the setting?

Comment: Added the settings page image

Comment: For me, the minimal test version of your code with default contract settings gives the expected error once background checking completes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

It seems the compiler is too smart and sees no one is using the stack after the last line so he does not check it.

once I add stack.push(...) it gives me the error...

cant have the coputer to be too smart...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the squiggly lines, then you have to check 'Show squigglies':

[image]

The re-build the project, wait for the static analysis to finish and you will have both warnings in 'Output' window (if you're not running the 'Ultimate' version of VS, these can be easy to miss) and the lines under suspicious code.

[Edit] By the way, I always run with the 'Standard Contract Requires' Assembly Mode.

Then after the example build:
[image]

and in the IDE:

[image]